# Is there a Maven dependency for jmeter

Tags: maven, jmeter, jmeter-maven-plugin

I am planning to write the jmeter test in java and I understand that we can copy the jar files from jmeter installations into the build path of my java project. But to make things easier do we have the maven dependecy which can be easily loaded in POM to download all the necessary jmeter files in my java project.

Comment: in maven repository you can find something about Jmeter. this is the [link](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.jmeter)

Comment: Why don't you write your JMeter tests and then make use of [*jmeter-maven-plugin*](https://github.com/jmeter-maven-plugin/jmeter-maven-plugin) to run them?

Comment: @aribeiro - I have an existing java project that already have a tons of useful code that I need for my tests(mostly test data creation). So, if I have my project java code and jmeter test at one place, it would be easier.
I know that, I can package my project Jars and put it in the jmeter installation directory, but I dont like the Beanshell editor inside jmeter and Also the error messages while debugging are not informative in the jmeter logs.

Answer (score 3):

It is, i.e. you can plug [Apache JMeter Core](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.jmeter/ApacheJMeter_core/2.13) like:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.jmeter</groupId>
    <artifactId>ApacheJMeter_core</artifactId>
    <version>2.13</version>
</dependency>
```

See

- [org.apache.jmeter](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.jmeter) artifacts group for available modules
- [Five Ways To Launch a JMeter Test without Using the JMeter GUI](https://blazemeter.com/blog/5-ways-launch-jmeter-test-without-using-jmeter-gui)
- [jmeter-from-code](https://bitbucket.org/blazemeter/jmeter-from-code/src) reference project

Answer (score 2):

You're right. Using Maven with its [dependency mechanism](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Dependencies) is far better than to "*copy the jar files from [...] installations into the build path of my java project*" in general.

JMeter is available in [Maven's Central Repository](http://search.maven.org/#search|ga|1|jmeter).

See also the [`jmeter-maven-plugin`](https://github.com/jmeter-maven-plugin/jmeter-maven-plugin) mentioned in [aribeiro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1346996/aribeiro)'s comment.

Comment: Thanks @Gerold and @ Hohenheim for the dependencies.

But I get an error in the POM on adding the dependencies. Below is the error:-
Multiple annotations found at this line:
 - Missing artifact commons-pool2:commons-pool2:jar:2.3
 - Missing artifact commons-math3:commons-math3:jar:

Comment: No worries. I resolved this error. For some reason my Maven was messed up. Thanks Anyways!!!

Comment: np bro @pune06 happy for you